# How to store cookies from Webdriver Sampler in HTTP Cookie Manager - JMeter

Tags: webdriver, jmeter

I have created Thread Group that contains :
`User Defined Variables (FedAuth_v,FedAuth1_v)` 
`HTTP Cookie Manager (FedAuth - value:${FedAuth_v}` and `FedAuth1 - value:${FedAuth1_v}`

Then i Have `jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler` with code

```
 var vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()
var cookie1=WDS.browser.manage().getCookieNamed("FedAuth").toString()
var cookie2=WDS.browser.manage().getCookieNamed("FedAuth1").toString()

vars.put('FedAuth_v',cookie1) 
vars.put('FedAuth1_v',cookie2)
```

After this sampler i need to use this cookies in HTTP request , but it fails and it still use initial value of `FedAuth1_v` and `FedAuth_v`

Is there any way to realize it ?

To add, my HTTP Request uses https protocol, proxy.
I have tried to check "secure" option in HTTP Cookie Manager but with no results.

[image]

Comment: Not clear whts step exactly you implement.Please share screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by this steps:
Changed cookie Policy to compatible
Changed cookie Implementation to HC3CookieHandler

and the last but not least, Internet Explorer Driver has got some problems with getting cookies named, changed to Chrome Driver and now everything works